# 100Hz monitor not working by default on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, refresh-rate

I have [this MSI 34inch 100Hz monitor](https://www.msi.com/Monitor/Optix-MAG341CQ) and I'm having a weird issue with it. I'm using it as a second monitor and when windows starts or resumes and if the monitor is at 100Hz it won't show anything, and the laptop screen will blink each 3-4 seconds (like it's trying to make it work), but if I manually set the refresh rate in windows to 60Hz and then to 100Hz it works at 100Hz, so it goes:

Widows starts/resume and monitor is at 100Hz and windows at 100Hz -> it doesn't work
Then change in windows to 60Hz -> it works at 60Hz
Then change it again to 100Hz -> it works at 100Hz
What can I do to not have to manually set the refresh rate to 100Hz every time the monitor shuts down?

Note: if I leave it at 60Hz it always works, at resuming or starting up, but that's not why I bought a 100Hz monitor.

And, I just reset my laptop and installed all updates and updated the drivers with NVidia GeForce Experience

Comment: This monitor, the Optix MAG341CQ, also has [a driver](https://www.msi.com/Monitor/support/OPTIX-MAG341CQ#down-driver&Win10%2064). Install it, and Windows might better recognize this monitor. Click on "Others Drivers" to see the driver.

Comment: Tried it but it's still the same :/ thanks tho

Answer (score 0):

You can try this settings from an old post in Reddit. I hope is not a problem to paste the link here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/comments/7h9bnu/psafor_people_with_dual_monitors_with_different/.

**PSA:** ***For people with dual monitors with different refresh rates
Discussion***

**Hello!!**

This thread applies to anyone with a dual monitor setup with different refresh rates and on windows 10.The resolution of both of the monitors can be different and a Nvidia gpu

**Problem:**

So gamers who had 2 or more monitors with different refresh rates(144hz primary and 60hz secondary) and are running windows 10 would have the problem when the refresh rate of the primary 144hz monitor dip to the refresh rate of the second monitor when anything was playing or any animation on the second monitor.At the end of the thread i will leave how to replicate this problem.

**Some examples**

[Video for a better explaination](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QaKL5x4wzNo)

[Another subreddit which might help you but it did not fix for me](https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/comments/5o32vs/psa_for_people_with_144hz_60hz_dual_monitor_with/)

This issue has been there for like the past 2 years.I have seen a butt load of posts on every single forum about this forum but none had an actual fix.

So the point of even having a secondary monitor becomes useless and just switch it off to get the higher refresh rate.

**Solution**

First make sure you are running a legit copy of windows 10 and updated to the latest version of it.

Next sign up for the Windows Insider Program and follow the instructions and update to the latest insider version.It may take 10 to 20 mins to download

Next go to your nvidia control panel and click on **adjust desktop size and resolution**.Set both your monitors to "Perform Scaling on" to your GPU and not the display which is the default.[image: adjust desktop size and resolution]

If you watch twitch streams or youtube videos or basically anything to do with chrome then you need to do this step or you can skip it.

Go to your settings in chrome and click on advanced options at the bottom and [disable hardware acceleration] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/8s5ZF.jpg).

If none of this works the only solution is to get a cheap gpu like gt 710 or 730 and use it solely for the 60hz monitor xD

**How to check if you have this problem or not**

To verify if you are getting 144hz use the [Testufo site](https://testufo.com/).Use it on firefox as it's kinda buggy on chrome and it seems to work perfectly on firefox(make sure to disable hardware acceleration in firefox if you experience problems).So run the testufo site on firefox on your main 144hz monitor and chrome with a youtube video playing on the 60hz monitor and check the fps on the site on your main monitor you will be able to see the actual fps your gpu is posting.

PS:If you run 2 144hz monitors you wont experience this problem.

If you are using different display connectors for both your monitors you can still experience this problem.

I have ONLY checked on Nvidia cards and this is does not effect amd users

If you are using windows 7 you can just disable Aero.The above guide is only for windows 10